# Cannot make @JsonSubType working with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I cannot make the Jackson `@JsonSubType` working in my SpringBoot application.

I've defined the following "configuration class"

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerSubtypes(AbstractKpi.class, AbstractKpiView.class,
                ApplicationObsolescenceKpiView.class, ManualEnumKpiView.class,
                ManualEnumKpiView.class, ApplicationObsolescenceKpi.class,
                ManualNumericKpi.class, ManualEnumKpi.class);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

In the classes list above, I've the following annotation

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class AbstractKpiView {

    Long id;

    Long version;...

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public class ManualNumericKpiView extends AbstractKpiView {

    Float minValue;

    Float maxValue;...
```

My `RestController` serialize my objects into JSON format but the `@class` attributte is never added.

The same classes work correctly in a pure Java application with just Jackson library (i.e. outside of SpringBoot)

I did not find any sample that works with SpringBoot
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I returned a `List<AbstractKpiView>...` and Jackson does not use the annotations in that case.

So I created a class that embed my collection, and finally it works!

The problem was that is return a collection of.... I embed the collection into a POJO and everything is fine now.